# Android: setOnClickListener to Buttons. Firing twice when pressed too quick

Tags: android, button, listener

I have a problem with an app i'm currently making for Android phones. I have an Activity that has two Buttons. The point is if i press both buttons fast enough (that's not a good user behaviour), those two buttons fire, while i want just to fire (at very most) only one of them. This a code fragment to example what I mean:

```
public class ActivityLevels extends Activity {

private boolean launched;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Set the content view of the screen
    setContentView(R.layout.levels);

    //Set lauched flag to false
    launched = false;

    //Initialize buttons
    Button loadLevel01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonLoadLevel01);
    Button loadLevel02 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonLoadLevel02);

    //Set Button Listeners
    loadLevel01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            launchGame(0);
        }
    });

    loadLevel02.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            launchGame(1);
        }

    });
}

private void launchGame(int level) {

    //Just launch the activity if !lanched
    if(!launched) {
        launched = true;
        //Start Activity
    }
}
}
```

I've been checking the internet for a week or so, and didn't find any approach to prevent this. As far as i've discovered, looks like that someone has already posted a similar issue here: [Issue 20073:   Button onClick listener can be fired twice even if button is disabled immediately in listener](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20073)

Btw, i've also tryed to disable the button just immediately before the "launchGame(int)" call, but not achieved anything.
This code is just an adapted fragment of the whole activity. I think that's ok to understand what i mean, but if you need any other description, please let me know.

Thanks in advance, and sorry for any spelling mistakes, my english is not very good at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I actually solved my question. The point was to make my method `launchGame(int level)` sychronized, so it can't be accessed more than once before it finishes. This way, let's say we have two threads from click listeners, because i pressed the button one and button two very very quick: with a synchronized method, it will be called `lauchGame(1)`, finish the action, and then `launchGame(2)` with the `boolean launched` flag setted to `true`.

This is what i've done:

```
private void synchronized launchGame(int level) {

    //Just launch the activity if !lanched
    if(!launched) {
        launched = true;
        //Start Activity
    }
}
```

Anyways, many thanks for all of your answers!

Comment: Make sure you mark your answer as "Accepted" so others can learn of your solution.  Cheers~

Answer (score 1):

You could use one onclicklistener for both of them and protect all the contents with a mutex.

Comment: This should work. Additionally, you don't even need to use the same listener, just synchronize on the same object.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. Could you please explain with a little more detail about your suggest? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `OnClickListener` of the "other" Button to `null` within the one of the clicked Button.

Comment: I've tried this too, but dont work either. The "other" buttons are set to null after their listener triggers. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, clear the onclicklistener on anything you don't want called.  I'd vote for that.  However, you could also try calling 'finish' on this activity in the button click handler.  I'm not sure that'll be the flow you want, but I think it'll prevent the other calls (haven't tried it, though).

Comment: I think what you say is not appropiate for my scenario. The resumed fact is, i'm in screen A, that have 15 buttons (one for each level). When the user press one button, i start the game activity (B), and when it finishes the activity A reads the result and show scores. So i have this: Activity A (15 buttons) --choose one of them--> go Activity B and configure it --finish game--> return to Activity A and read results. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

try to block the button with your launched state

```
loadLevel01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (launched) return;            
        launchGame(0);
    }
});
```

Comment: this should be the simplest way to do it.

Comment: i've tried this, but doesn't work. If i press the two buttons fast enough, they seem to both pass the if(lauched) return; I put a Log.d between that statement and the launchGame(0), and it appear two times, so this solution is not correct. Thanks for answering anyways!